# PHP path with Apache authentication

Tags: php, apache

I need to create a secure directory in Apache2.

I have a directory `/var/www` with my login page and `/var/www/secure/` with all the rest of my PHP, JavaScript and HTML.

I send a login request, and after a successful response, I want to run the rest of my site from `/var/www/secure/`, so I make a call to `/var/www/secure/index.php` from `/var/www/login.php`.

All the paths in `/var/www/secure/index.php` are relative (to `/var/www/secure/`), but then I get an error (in the Apache log):

> File does not exist: /var/www/scripts, referer: my_IP_Address/login.php

Where the script's directory located at `/var/www/secure/scripts` is the same as `/var/www/secure/index.php`.

My question is: Why does the path remain `/var/www/` just as the login.php file?

How can I take care of the path once I call `/var/www/secure/index.php`?

Comment: If we can't see your PHP code it's difficult for us to help you

Comment: `chdir(__DIR__);` in `secure/index.php`.